# How can I introduce dcast into data.table chain without using piping?

Tags: r, data.table

data.table is graceful and intuitive with the chains rule. Everything is just lined up like a machine. But sometimes we have to introduce some operation like `dcast` or `melt`.

How can I integrate all operation into the `[]`? Simply because it's more graceful, I admit.

```
DT <- data.table(A = rep(letters[1:3],4), B = rep(1:4,3), C = rep(c("OK", "NG"),6))
DT.1 <- DT[,.N, by = .(B,C)] %>% dcast(B~C)
DT.2 <- DT.1[,.N, by = .(NG)]
#   NG N
#1: NA 2
#2:  3 2

#same
DT <- data.table(A = rep(letters[1:3],4), B = rep(1:4,3), C = rep(c("OK", "NG"),6))[,.N, by = .(B, C)] %>% 
dcast(B~C) %>% .[,.N, by =.(NG)]
```

Can I remove the `%>%` and integrate into the `[]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using `.SD` to this end:

```
DT[, .N, by = .(B, C)
   ][, dcast(.SD, B ~ C)
     ][, .N, by = .(NG)]

   NG N
1: NA 2
2:  3 2
```

Comment: yeah? Smart! I didn't think of this trick. Trying now! thanks!

Comment: Came across this answer and was further wondering how you could do this but also modify in place at the same time?

Comment: Modify in place... in what sense? You want to add the `N` column to the original `data.table`?

Comment: forgetting about the last step in the chain in the example - if you can have the result of the second step in the chain be assigned to DT